# One-Hot Encoding After Joins on Melts via get_dummies and pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that I wish to one-hot encode after adding some labels. The below code works on toy examples, and is the approach I've taken in similar contexts. It does not scale however.  For example, with this dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1, 2],
                   'C1' : ['X1', 'X2'],
                   'C2' : ['X2', np.NaN],
                   'C3' : ['X3', np.NaN],
                   'C4' : ['X4', 'X4']})
```

At this point `df` consists of columns containing string values whose order does not matter. So an immediate `pd.get_dummies(df, prefix = '', prefix_sep = '', columns = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4']` will output a one-hot-encoded dataframe with two C2 columns, which is undesirable, for example.

Entries (`id`) may have varying lengths (hence, the `np.NaN`). Any given `id` will not contain repeats of entries. However, these string values might fall under another category which I wish to add a label to.

```
label_list = pd.DataFrame({'strval': ['X1','X2','X3','X4'],
                           'label' : [np.NaN, 'red', 'blue', 'red']})
```

I then melt df and join on the string vals to get labels in appropriate position

```
dflong = pd.melt(df, id_vars = ['id'],
                 value_vars = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4'],
                 value_name = 'strval')

dflab = dflong.merge(label_list, on = 'strval')
```

This works, however in my real dataset 1 million rows becomes 20 million on the melt. get_dummies also encodes everything separately on it's own line. I follow with a `pd.pivot_table` to shape it into the appropriate format.

```
dflab_gd = pd.get_dummies(dflab.drop(columns = ['variable']),
                          columns = ['strval', 'label'],
                          prefix = '', prefix_sep = '')
```

Now I want to flatten this result so that there is one entry per `id`.

```
dflab_gd_flt = dflab_gd.pivot_table(index = ['id'], aggfunc = 'any', 
fill_value = 0).astype(int)
```

I like this approach because I can also preserve the labels as counts in cases where I care to count how many times a strval fitting the same label shows up by changing the `aggfunc`.

My question then is this: this method does not scale well at all. Is there another way of assigning the labels and obtaining a one-hot encoded dataframe (or one-hot encoded for strvals and counts for labels) that is more computationally efficient? Perhaps one that doesn't involve reshaping the long results of a melt? After get_dummies is applied to my actual melted set, I have a 0/1 dataframe that is 20 million rows by 30,000 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do one-hot encoding. If you put 'label' and 'strval' in the same column and do a group by you should get what you need.

```
df_concat = pd.concat(
    (dflab.drop(columns=['label']).rename({'strval': 'val'}, axis=1), 
     dflab.drop(columns=['strval']).rename({'label': 'val'}, axis=1)), 
    axis=0)

# use .any() or .count() as you would set aggfunc='any' or 'count'
dfg = df_concat.groupby(['id', 'val']).count()

# pivot to go from long to wide dataframe
dfg.reset_index().pivot('id', 'val').fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Comment: This works for both the toy example above and my real dataset. I had some complications that led to some confusion, however, and reading the docs (admittedly not in-depth -- a weekend task) did not entirely clarify.

The `melt` operation introduces the 'variable' column. For the real dataset, I attempted to drop it, after which the pivot yielded an empty dataframe. I did not realize this for some time -- what is the rationale here? The pivot depends on an extra column for aggregate output?

Otherwise dropping the extra indexing ('variable', 'X1') gets me exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: The 'variable' column stores the column name in the original DataFrame. In this case it does not store any useful information. It is the groupby step that has the problem. If you group by a dataframe with all of its columns you are left with no columns on which pandas can apply aggregate functions.

Comment: `groups = df_concat.drop(columns='variable').groupby(['id', 'val'])`

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(((k[0], k[1], len(v)) for k,v in groups.indices.iteritems()), columns=['id', 'var', 'cnt'])`